# Collectors.toSet changes order

Tags: java, collections

I'm seeing an interesting behavior in stream processing of String arrays.

I'm doing something like this

```
String s =  "1_2_string";
String[] arr = s.split("_");
final Set<String> CAST_PATTERN = Set.of("string", "string2");
Arrays.stream(arr)
        .filter(id -> !CAST_PATTERN.contains(id))
        .map(Long::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Expected outcome should be a set [1,2]
but actual outcome is [2,1]
Collectors.toSet() creates an HashSet and not a SortedSet, so it should not mess up the order of data.
Not sure why!!

Comment: I think, the 'order' in a hashset is somewhat indetermined or depends on the actual hashcode of each value.

Comment: The order in an unordered set "should be" whatever it happens to come out as. They have no guaranteed order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, a Set does not have any guarantees about iteration order.

If you need a defined order, you can use `Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)` (for natural order of elements) or `Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)` (for insertion order).